# How to create a scrollable box in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a box of Terms and conditions in which data can be scrolled. I tried it using `TextInput` like below but it doesn't scrolls.

```
 <TextInput 
        multiline={true}
        value={data}
        editable={false}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        style={styles.termsAndConditionsStyle}
  />
```

**second alternative**

I also tried it this way, it works but it gives me a yellow screen **warning** which says - You are binding a method component to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See ScrollView.

```
 <ScrollView  style={styles.termsAndConditionsStyle}>
           <Text>
               // some large text
           </Text>
   </ScrollView>
```

**Solution** - Actually I imported `ScrollView` from `react-native-gesture-handler` instead of `react-native`

Comment: Not sure why you are using ``TextInput`` instead of ``ScrollView``. 

Check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview for proper example.

``ScrollView`` is meant for rendering such UI not ``TextInput``.

Comment: @SandipNirmal Please check my edited question **second alternative**

Comment: can you add code of constructor() ? or whaterver place you're using bind()

Comment: @JaydeepGalani please check edited question. And no, I'm not using any bind() in my code.

Comment: it seems there is somthing else that is creating this yellow warning, can you reproduce it on snack.expo.io ? just copy paste everything there and share link here.

Comment: I'm using React Native version 0.55.3 Could that be a reason somehow?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani actually I'm working on a project which is made in the old version of React Native and I cannot update it because the app gives me an error if I update it since there are other old libraries too.

Comment: no i am also using 0.55.X , this is not version issue!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188785/discussion-between-jaydeep-galani-and-shubham-bisht).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `<ScrollView>`?.

You can use this to create scrolling functionality.

well its pretty simple, just warp your components in `<ScrollView>  ... </ScrollView>`and
style it as per your need.

if height of components together exceeds for `<ScrollView>`, it becomes scrollable.

[see docs at react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview)

**EDIT:**

Its importing mistake, import `scrollview` from `react-native` rather than `react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: Please check my edited question **second alternative**

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much Jaydeep, you've been of great help once again. :)

Comment: I just realized that my Scroll is working fine but I cannot have a constant height, if possible can you please show me a small demo code for it? :)

Comment: @ShubhamBisht you need to fix the height, either in percentage or static whatever you want or else it will use whole height available and may be other component will be hidden below scrollview. 
If you want your content to be in 10% of whole screen give `height:"10%"` or import height from Dimension and use `height:height/10`

Comment: I did give a constant height to `ScrollView` but my box is of same height (not as I want it to be)  though it's still scrolling

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView>       
              <Text>
                  Add your text
              </Text>      
          </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
}
```

**EDIT:**

Its importing mistake, import `scrollview` from `react-native` rather than `react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: Please check my edited question **second alternative**